# Google news - publishercenter not indexing our English speaking articles

Tags: seo, google, google-news

Is it possible that google automatically disbands non international domains for English language in google news?

We have a website in Croatian language, with one English subsection.

We have 2 news publications in our publishercenter.
Our goal is to reach traffic from outside of Croatia, so tourists can read news and inform themselves if they want to travel to Croatia.

One is
oursite.hr, set to croatia only as a croatian language.

Second one is
oursite.hr/english, set to worldwide as an english speaking website, with separate RSS feeds (only english written categories)

Articles appear correctly if you search our publication directly, and visit publication homepage, but when you try to search articles by exact title, even tho it has only 200 results in google news search, there are zero articles from our publication (tried VPN from multiple countries).
All results are from .com and .co.uk domains and .net domains.

Articles written in Croatian language appears correctly in search.

Comment: Your question does not have complete details. Are you using meta hreflang? Are you using a meta-canonical link? What is the performance indicator value for your website? What structured data is there in both language versions? It is impossible to analyze and identify the problem based on your abstract question.